# Installing and finding older versions of the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcodebuild

I'm trying to build for iOS 7 from the command line using a makefile, but I have already installed 8.4 SDK. I followed the standard procedure to install it using Xcode and it seems to be installed, as shown in the screen shot below.

[image]

However, when trying to find the SDK with `xcodebuild` I doesn't show. Here's my output:

```
$ xcodebuild -showsdks
2015-09-09 14:59:33.587 xcodebuild[85926:12435307] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 7FDF5C7A-131F-4ABB-9EDC-8C5F8F0B8A90 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/VVDocumenter-Xcode.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
OS X SDKs:
    OS X 10.9                       -sdk macosx10.9
    OS X 10.10                      -sdk macosx10.10

iOS SDKs:
    iOS 8.4                         -sdk iphoneos8.4

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 8.4             -sdk iphonesimulator8.4
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: So, to clarify, you're under the belief that to target iOS 7 you must use the iOS 7 SDK?

Comment: No. By linking against the correct SDK I get to find issues such as using APIs which are only available on later versions. It's mostly a sanity check.

Comment: You should update your question with that information.

Comment: I guess it should be enough to be as high in the comments as it is :) thank you, nonetheless